# Will deleting a pointer to an object in the destructor of a certain class automatically delete it from the heap?

Tags: c++

Everytime I was coding a game, I always utilized this piece of code for the destructor:

```
A::~A()
{
    delete this;
}
```

Will this actually delete an object on the heap when the scope for it is over?

Comment: _"Does this code make any sense..."_ No.  If `delete` was called on the original object you will get double (recursive) deletion.  If the original object was in the stack, then `delete` should not be called.

Comment: It always seemed to work fine. But if there is a problem with it, how can I check (if it's possible to do so) whether it's on stack or heap?

Comment: How will the destructor be called?

Comment: What is "the scope" of an object on the heap?

Comment: I dont think that this makes any sense at all. With objects on the stack the destructor is called automatically when the code block is left in which the variable was created. With an heap object the destructor is called when you free the memory with delete.

Comment: Also, why do you put this in your code if you don't understand what it does?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Well, no. How do we get to the destructor in the first place?

Comment: @juanchopanza Haha good point :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing this makes no sense as the destructor is called upon deletion of the object ( `delete` invokes the destructor), there's no reason to call `delete` again.  In the best case scenario where the object you are freeing is actually allocated by `new` you are doing a double `delete` on your object. In the other case you are calling `delete` on an object not created by `new`. Both are undefined behavior.